# Checking for individual log lines with Python's testfixtures.LogCapture

Tags: python

I'm using the Python [testfixtures.LogCapture](http://testfixtures.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging.html) library to unit test logging output. This works fine for checking the complete log output of a method call:

```
with LogCapture() as captured_log:
    foo.do_something()

captured_log.check(
    ('root', 'INFO', 'first log message'),
    ('root', 'INFO', 'second log message'),
    ('root', 'INFO', 'third log message'),
)
```

**Is there any way to check that a single log entry is present, without checking all the surrounding lines?**

Something along the lines of:

```
# Pseudocode
captured_log.has_entry(
    ('root', 'INFO', 'second log message')
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LogCapture.actual()` to get a generator which will give you all of the log entries. Then you can see if your expected log entry is present.

It looks something like:

```
with LogCapture() as captured_log:
    foo.do_something()

expected_log = (
    ('root', 'INFO', 'second log message')
)

assert expected_log in LogCapture.actual()
```

API doc: https://testfixtures.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#testfixtures.LogCapture.actual

Comment: `assert expected_log in captured_log.actual()` works for me